# url rewrite for submit in php

Tags: php

Do anyone know how can I rewrite a URL in php for the submit action?

Example:

I have a code as following:

I call to the page by using the following link www.assignment.com (I have set the index to test.php) and test.php will display the following code.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="phone" value="">
  <input class="submit_btn" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

when I clicked on the submit button, it will post to test.php to do the action and the display the same input page. However once submit button been clicked, the url link will become www.assignment.com/test.php. any way that I can rewrite the url to www.assignment.com after submit instead of www.assignment.com/test.php?

Comment: What does `test.php` do different to the page that contains the above form? You could integrate the code from `test.php` into the page that contains the form, meaning on submittal, it will simply submit to it self, keeping the url the same as previous.

Comment: why not just do <form action="http://www.assignment.com/test.php" method="post"> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `test.php` is run when `http://assignment.com/` is loaded, you could just change the form target to:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `header("Location: www.assignment.com");` at the end of your `test.php` script.